# how to label edges of google's fusion table network graph?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Is there any way in google's fusion table network graph, where we can label the edges?
Currently we can assign the weight's to the graph but not the label.
Please reply how we should get this done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not supported.  Please feel free to file a feature request: http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/issues/list